# Changing heading style of a section

Tags: formatting, sections-paragraphs

I'm porting my CV from Word to latex. I want to include my publication list, but I want to split it into two halves, my thesis and my journal articles, with the appropriate subheadings. Since academic references are always nasty to manually write, I'm using BibTeX to keep track of them appropriately.

This is how I want it to look like:

[image: Current]

This is how it currently looks:

[image: Latex's version]

This is generated by the following code (Using http://www.latextemplates.com/template/medium-length-professional-cv from the Internet):

```
\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} % Document margins

\name{Random Joe} % Your name
\address{Who lives nowhere, really} % Your address
\address{(555) 555 5121~$\cdot$~ email: Joe@nobody.com} % Your phone number and email

\begin{document}

\begin{rSection}{Education}

{\bf University, city} \hfill {\em August 2013} \\ 
PhD \& Engineering \\
 \smallskip \\

\end{rSection}

\begin{rSection}{Work Experience}

\begin{rSubsection}{Nonwhere}{August 2007 - August 2013}{Graduate Research Assistant}{Nowhere, FAR}
\item What do grad students do anyway?
\end{rSubsection}


\begin{rSubsection}{Nowhere}{Summer 2006}{Intern}{Someother place, AWAY}

\item Intern

\end{rSubsection}

%-----------------
\end{rSection}


\begin{rSection}{Skills}

\begin{rSubsection}{Computering}{}{}{}

\item Been on the internets. 
\item Note much to see there

\end{rSubsection}



\end{rSection}


\begin{rSection}{Other}

Native fluency in English. Somewhat


\end{rSection}

\begin{rSection}{CONFERENCE PRESENTATIONS}

\begin{rSubsection}{GRAD STUDENTS Annual Meeting }{2012}{Hell-sinsky}
\item Are grad students really useful for research? 
\end{rSubsection}


\end{rSection}

\pagebreak[3]

\begin{rSection}{AWARDS, HONORS}

\item Primary author (\cite{Lee2009} below) of paper selected as the cover of the issue.
\nocite{Lee2012}

\end{rSection}

\pagebreak[3]

\begin{rSection}{Publications}

\begin{rSubsection}{Thesis}{}{}
\item PhD Thesis (2013) ``Grad students: Victims or Whimps?'' Studets-r-us, GA
\end{rSubsection}

\end{rSection}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Refereed Journal Publications}
\bibliography{Resume}

\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Does the answer solve your problem?

Comment: Not really, but that's probably because I'm very new to Tex. I worked around it (manually typing the references), for now.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\renewenvironment{rSection}[1]{ % 1 input argument - section name
  \nameskip\nameskip
  \MakeUppercase{\bfseries #1} % Section title
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \nameskip
  \begin{list}{}{ % List for each individual item in the section
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0em} % Margin within the section
  }
  \item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}
```

and you will have the following result:

[image]