# List style and section style

Tags: lists, line-breaking, line-spacing

I'm trying to change list style with a section style, but I have a problem.

It looks without a new line between the first item and "Hello"

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

{\bf Hello:}
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep, nolistsep] 
    \item Autocomplete
    \item Randomized queue and deque
\end{itemize}
{\bf Hello1:} 
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep, nolistsep] 
    \item Autocomplete
    \item Ramdomized queue and deque 
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

But this solution adds new line between first item and "Hello".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{ % 1 input argument - section name
  \sectionskip
  \MakeUppercase{\bf #1} % Section title
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \begin{list}{}{ % List for each individual item in the section
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0em} % Margin within the section
  }
  \item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{rSection}{University Projects}
{\bf Hello:}
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep, nolistsep] 
    \item Autocomplete
    \item Ramdomized queue and deque
\end{itemize}

{\bf Hello1:}
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep, nolistsep] 
    \item Autocomplete
    \item Ramdomized queue and deque
\end{itemize}

\end{rSection}

\end{document}
```

A rSection function I copied from here: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156869/changing-heading-style-of-a-section#*=*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156869/changing-heading-style-of-a-section#_=_)

Please, help me remove this empty line.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! IUt can't be compiled. Where are `\sectionskip` and `\sectionlineskip` defined?

Comment: @Bernard, It can be compiled. You can check my project on [overleaf](https://ru.overleaf.com/read/fjbjpzckqbqg)

Comment: I'm sorry, but on my system, it can't be compiled. The two commands I mentioned are not defined by default in LaTeX. Actually, googling for them, they seem to come from the old, deprecated LaTeX 2.09 `resume.cls`.